# Special characters no longer working

Tags: windows-7, windows

Up until a few days ago i could type special characters mainly German umlauts by using ALT+ Number Pad . eg. Alt + 0252 would produce "ü" . For some reason this no longer works.

All the language and region settings are set correctly.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Is NumLock enabled?

Comment: This stopped working for me on my XP desktop some time ago, but frequent internet searches have not found any reason, nor any solution. I think it happened after a patch Tuesday update, but I don't use special characters all the time, so I was not aware of which group of updates caused it. (@gronostaj - it always used to work on a full keyboard with NumLock off, but now it doesn't work whether off or on.)

Comment: @AFH I have just tried it on Windows 7 and it doesn't work without NumLock, but does work with it. I don't know what caused the problem in your case, but in banflescrum's case it could be NumLock.

Comment: As a work-round I use the virtual keyboard in Google Translate, then cut and paste into whatever program I am running (this also helps my inadequate German and vestigial Norwegian!). Note that while the virtual keyboard is active, the PC keyboard is also remapped, but only for that page's input box.

Comment: I've tried NumLock and the function button without success. I've spent hours searching google but no one else seems to have thiis problem. The strange thing is some work. If I use alt + 0223 I can produce ß and with alt + 0220 I get Ü.

Comment: I've just realised that if a press alt + 0228 which used to give me "ä" is now pasting text from clipboard.